# function detail view in django

Tags: python, django

For almost 5h I can't make detail view.

My app name -movies

My views:
"

```
def actor_view(request):
    actor_list = Actor.objects.all()
    context = {'actor_list': actor_list}
    return render(request,'movies/actor.html',context)

def actor_detail_view(request,id):
    actorrr=get_object_or_404(Actor,id=id)
    context={
        'actorrr':actorrr,
    }
    return render(request,"movies/actor_detail_view.html",context)
```

My model

```
class Actor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_of_birth  = models.DateField()
    age=models.IntegerField( null=True)
    net_worth = models.TextField(max_length=140, null=True)
    picture=models.URLField(default = '')
    children =models.TextField(max_length=140, null=True)
    marital_status=models.TextField(max_length=140, null=True)
```

My actor html:

```
{% load static %}
{% block mainbody %}
{% for actor in actor_list  %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>List of actors we have</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style_actor.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="card" >
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="{{ actor.picture }}" alt="No poster in datebase"    width="289" height="345">
        </div>
    <div class="card-text">
      <h2>
        <a href="/movies/actor_detail/{{actor.id }}">{{ actor.name }}</a>  
      </h2>
      <p>{{movie.pilot}}</p>
    </div>
     <div class="card-imdb-score">
        <p 
         >Age: {{ actor.age }} 
        </p>
     </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

My actor_detail html

```
<h6>TEST</h6>
```

movies url:

```
path('actor_detail_view/<int:id>',views.actor_detail_view,name='actor_detail_view'),
```

and the main url:

```
path('<int:id>/',views.actor_detail_view,name="actor_detail_view")
```

So I have no idea how to make urls and what to place in actor.html in href url.I've made many tutorials and still couldn't do it.

Comment: You pass the object as name `actorrr`, not `actor` to the template.

Comment: Didn't fix the problem cuz this is the only variable

Comment: but you pass `{'actorrr': actorrr}` as context, hence the `actor` in for example `{{ actor.age }}` does *not* exists.

Comment: What is exactly your problem? the link doesn't work? any errors?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommends to you set the name of variable **actorrr** correctly.
If you're using Pycharm IDEA, the idea helps you to avoid problems with names of variables or spaces, following [PEP08](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Some tips:

1. verify your urls.py file, to see if exists "/movies/actor_detail/{{actor.id }}
2. Probably, you have to add django template structure to appear the data of actor detail HTML, without for looping, because it's just one data.

Comment: I can't find the solution :(

Answer (score 0):

your link to the actor detail page must be like this :

```
<a href={% url 'actor_detail_view' actor.id %}
```

also it's better to use django generic views to get detailed models.

Comment: After changing to  <a href={% url 'actor_detail_view' actor.id %}  still same :(

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use CBVs, in this case, DetailView, I had same project and I put code here to use:

```
class DetailedActor(DetailView):
template_name = 'your_template'
model = models.YourModel

def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    return context
```

then in your template, you have an instance of your model whit a specific actor! just don't forget to pass the id when you render to the URL assigned to this view